# Access JSON file in React without importing it

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, create-react-app

I have been importing data in the form of a `JSON` file into a React component:

`import data from '../../public/json/data.json';`

I am using the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) tool, and when I run `npm run build`, as expected the `data.json` file is bundled as part of the `build/static/main.js` file.

What I would like is for this `data.json` file *not* to be bundled but to be referenced at run-time each time the component runs. I.e. so that it can be edited in the built app and for these edits to show in the app. I thought that by including it in my `public` (as opposed to `src`) folder this would work, but of course I am still `importing` it so it is bundled. Is there a way to reference it without bundling it?

Comment: I think this can be achieved using Code-splitting where you can split code into an on demand loaded chunk. Refer https://gist.github.com/gaearon/0a2213881b5d53973514,
https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html
for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fetch API to retrieve the JSON file asynchronously.

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch for example implementations.